# Work out min and hours

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a minute value and i want to have to 2 string values one with how many hours and the other with the minutes, e.g.:

Value - 121 minutes

string hours = 2
string minutes = 1

Value - 58 minutes

string hours = 0
string minutes = 58

How can I work this out in C#?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var span = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(121);
var hours = ((int)span.TotalHours).ToString();     
var minutes = span.Minutes.ToString();
```

The ToString() is because you asked for string values ...

TotalHours are the complete hours in the TimeSpan, they can be more than 24 (whereas the "Hours" field has a maximum of 24)

Oh, and on second thought: Why use the TimeSpan and not calculate it yourself? Because TimeSpan is already there debugged & tested by Microsoft, it has a nice clean interface (looking at the code you easily see whats going on without having to follow a calculation mentally) and it easily extends to further solutions. (Have the input in seconds? Use TimeSpan.FromSeconds(). Want the days? Use span.TotalDays ...)

***Update:***

I just noticed mistake in my answer: TotalHours returns a fractional value of all the hours, so we have to truncate it to an integer before converting it to a string.

Comment: This won't pad minutes with zeros. Adding ToString("00") should fix it.

Comment: @Coincoin: look at OP's example for 121 minutes. No padding is required.

Answer (score 8):

Use a Timespan struct and its [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx) method.

Comment: He said he had a minute and wanted to convert it to strings, not the other way round.

Comment: Timespan is still the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = 121;
int hours = value / 60; // 2
int minutes = value % 60; // 1

string strHours = hours.ToString();
string strMinutes = minutes.ToString();
```

Comment: Using TimeSpan is the OO way, but this is short and sweet.

Comment: I looked into TimeSpan using Reflector: all results are counted by multiplication of ticked milliseconds. I believe my method can be faster!

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = 121;
int hours = value / 60;
int minutes = value % 60;
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a perfectly valid way of getting hours/minutes from a total minutes value and is the same as abatishchev's answer except for the .ToString()'s

Comment: @Craig: I screwed. There was an error in another answer and downvoted that one by mistake. I removed both -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = 121;
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value);

// gives you the rounded down value of 2
int hours = timeSpan.Hours; 

// gives you the minutes left of the hour
int minutes = value - (hours * 60);
```

Comment: Why not use TimeSpan.Minutes here? This will return 1 in this case, as opposed to TimeSpan.TotalMinutes which returns 121

Comment: Actually, TotalMinutes returns a double that could return 121.3523 or some number if you are doing a difference in date.  Which, yes, would be casted down to 121 if you are casting to an Int32.

TimeSpam.Minutes I did not test.  But, if it returns "1" instead of "121", then that's it.